# best practice for overriding ExtJS model getters & setters

Tags: extjs

i want to intercept field get/set on a model so that i can transform the values before they get displayed as well as before they get stored in the model.  in this case, i want to store uriencoded data in the model, but display decoded values.

when i directly override the get/set methods i see that they are being used by the proxy to put raw data into the model.  i dont want to override that process and i am not even sure how to tell whether it is the proxy loading a model or the ui.

what is the best method for this?  convert, btw, appears to be a poor choice.  it is not 2-way and live.

Comment: `convert()` _is_ two-way method. I use it for example to convert back and forth decimal color codes to hex.

Comment: Just so I understand.. (1) when retrieving data, you are encoding data on the server before the ajax get and then decoding it before displaying data to end-user?  (2) when passing data in the URL, you encode, then decode in Ext JS when you use the data?  (3) When saving data, you have Ext JS encode, then pass to the server and decode before storing?

Comment: how is convert a 2-way function?  it looks to me like it only gets called when something is reading a value from a record ie. myRec.get('field1').  is there a convert equivalent getting called during a write operation ie. myRec.set('field1', 'new value')?

Answer (score 4):

Note: I have not tested this code, so use the concepts and comment later if you have questions.

When you define your Ext.data.Model class for your data entities (use Ext.data.Record for Ext JS 3), add a convert function as part of your Ext.data.Field property instance.  This can be done for all fields if you want, but probably not recommended.

I'm new to this framework, so one thing I do not know how to do is use the "this.self" notation in the convert function in case you are extending another class in your Model class.  For example, if you do not have a default value defined in the Employee class and it inherits from another class (like Employee for example), but the Employee constructor sets that property, it'll take the value defined in the super class (base class or parent class) constructor when you encode the data.  Right now, it just gets the EmployeeDeveloper.dataValue property.

```
Ext.define('EmployeeDeveloper', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    { name: 'name', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Paul' },
    { name: 'profession', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Ext JS developer' },
    { name: 'salary', type: 'float', defaultValue: '95000' },
    { name: 'dataValue', type: 'string',
      convert: function(value, record) {
        // feel free to use value and record parameters in this function
        return encodeData(record.get('dataValue'));  // you may have to use the "value" parameter instead of record.get('dataValue') if referencing the field in it's own convert function (haven't tested)
      }
    }
  ]
});

var empDev = Ext.create(
  'EmployeeDeveloper', 
  {
    name: 'MacGyver',
    dataValue: 'ABC'
  }, 
  'MacGyver', 
  123
);

var encodedDataValue = empDev.get('dataValue');
```

**Caution about convert:** If you are referencing a field that is defined below the convert function signature, the code will not know about it and won't be able to retrieve the value.

**OR IF YOU HAVE A CUSTOM CLASS BUT NOT USING THE MODEL CLASS...**

Tonight I also read about something else that's kind of neat in Ext JS.  They added auto getters and setters in Ext JS 4.  The new version of the framework automatically prefixes your property with "get", "set", "reset", or "apply" and capitalizes the first letter of the property inside of the "config" property of your defined class.

In regular JavaScript, they don't have real classes, but Sencha has made it possible to define a class (with the "define" function) and the ability to instantiate an object instance of your user defined class.

For example, suppose you have the following class defined:

```
Ext.define('Paul.MyClass'), {
  extend: 'Ext.Window',
  config: {
    name: 'Paul'
  }
});
```

If you create an instance of your object like so, you automatically have access to four functions.

```
var win = Ext.create('Paul.MyClass');  // create instance of MyClass object
var myName = win.getName();  // get name
win.setName('MacGyver');  // set name
win.resetName(); // this resets the value back to the default value ('Paul')
win.applyName();  // this calls custom code 
win.show();
```

I'd suggest overriding the apply* method with the logic you are suggesting.  Then calling win.get*(); afterward to get the new value.  It might be wise to have an extra encoded field for each field you plan on encoding so you don't have to manipulate your properties every time you access (get or set) your data in your proxies and/or stores.

```
Ext.define('Paul.MyClass'), {
  extend: 'Ext.Window',
  config: {
    name: 'Paul',
    dataValue: 'non encoded value of your data'
  }
  applyName: function(title) {
    this.name = this.name + ' ' + title;  // custom logic goes here
  }
  applyDataValue: function(encodeKey) {
    // get the encoded data value
    this.self.dataValue = 'encoded data value';  // custom logic goes here
  }
});
```

Comment: i am using ExtJS 4.1 as well as Sencha Touch 2.0 - so both have auto-getters and setters.  regarding convert, still not sure how it helps with writes, it only appears to be useful in converting reads.  perhaps i could override getters and setters, but it appeared to me as though the getters and setters are being called EVEN during the loading ie. model.add(newRec) operation, which is no good for me.

Comment: I haven't programmed in Ext JS yet.. just made a few widgets this weekend and have been reading a book on the subject.  I just got a job (entry level) where I'll be developing a data warehouse reporting tool with this framework for a local clinic, so I'll be learning quickly.  If I come across some info in this book or read it online, I will reply to you.  You may want to post a question on the sencha.com forum with this info.

Comment: what is model.add(newRec) not doing?

Comment: my problem concerns what model.add(newRec) IS doing.  it is calling the property getters and setters.  i only want my getters and setters to be called when the UI is accessing the model, not when the model is being loaded by the proxy

Comment: Can you try calling the showCallStack inside the getters and setters, for the scenarios you are describing, and see what is different or what variables are different?  This function will alert the call stack.  Then you can back track so you can sort of hack your getters/setters to return at the beginning (or be ignored) when you need them to, and just return the current value of the field/property instead of the encoded value.  http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=141861